# Can I use sql server log file for change tracking?

Tags: sql-server

Sql Server database have both mdf and ldf files. Mdf being the data and ldf being the change log. I have a need to track every "data" change in the database. Till now Ive used mirror tables with the same name but a dcr (data change record) schema. These are populated by triggers on insert, update, delete. Works fine but it's quite a bit of overhead.

Since I'm updating this application at the moment I thought now would be a good time to revisit this almost never used but somehow "required" feature. Can I use the Sql Server ldf file for this? Is the data all there on a per column change basis and is it simple to query?

For instance right now a user could say give me the record of customer x at 1400hrs 01/01/2013. Thats just a "between" query on the dcr.Customer table. Can I do this with ldf's.

If not is there an opensource option for this? Or is change tracking by triggers just how it's done?

Comment: There are some built in options for this depending on what sql server version and edition you have - please could you provide us with  the details of these?

Comment: A mix of Sql Server 2012 Express Edition and Standard editions depending on customer.... but primarily Express i.e. cheap ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Data Capture, which is the quickest and easiest way to do this, is unfortunately not available for Express.  Change Tracking is available on all editions but it will only tell you what row and column was changed, not what the values were before and after.

There is a codeplex project for doing CDC but it looks to be built along the lines of yours i.e. trigger based, which is in line with what I've been told before about how to do it without the expensive versions.

http://standardeditioncdc.codeplex.com/

Still - someone elses project might mean it's use could save you some time or they dedicated more time to improving performance, so it might be of use to you - even just for code perusal to compare implementations.